# Summer Cleanup Project #2: High View Closed Questions

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, deleted-questions

Last Week I cleaned up [high-view Duplicate questions](Summer Cleanup Project #1: Duplicate Review). This week I am tackling closed non-duplicate questions with over 1000 views.

## Project #2: High View Closed Questions

There are [currently 318 questions with over 1,000 views](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/search?q=views%3A1000). There are 15 non-duplicate [closed questions with over 1000 views](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/search?q=closed%3Ayes+views%3A1000) (duplicates removed manually). These 15 questions represent almost 5% of our high-view questions (if defined as 1,000 views). Many of these questions are likely victims of the [Stack Exchange™ MultiCollider SuperDropdown™](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11602/what-formula-should-be-used-to-determine-hot-questions), but there is the possibility that they are high views because they provide information that is valuable to users.

1. [Getting fired on the second day, how do I cope with it?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/911/getting-fired-on-the-second-day-how-do-i-cope-with-it)
2. [When and how to fire a unproductive engineer?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/12692/when-and-how-to-fire-a-unproductive-engineer)
3. [Does keeping one's desk extremely clean appear lazy?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/454/does-keeping-ones-desk-extremely-clean-appear-lazy)
4. [Is it unprofessional to play games during lunch hours?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/572/is-it-unprofessional-to-play-games-during-lunch-hours)
5. [Boss does not answer questions](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/10229/boss-does-not-answer-questions)
6. [Working late without overtime pay, good idea or not?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/915/working-late-without-overtime-pay-good-idea-or-not)
7. [Jokingly told my boss "I quit" on April Fools, and I think I just got fired](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/10769/jokingly-told-my-boss-i-quit-on-april-fools-and-i-think-i-just-got-fired)
8. [How does a non team player answer questions about team playing](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/11411/how-does-a-non-team-player-answer-questions-about-team-playing)
9. [Is it acceptable to use pirated software on the job?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/772/is-it-acceptable-to-use-pirated-software-on-the-job)
10. [I just got a job that I can't afford to go to, how to resolve?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/12939/i-just-got-a-job-that-i-cant-afford-to-go-to-how-to-resolve)
11. [Improving social interaction at work](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/4247/improving-social-interaction-at-work)
12. [Stuck in boring programming jobs](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/2951/stuck-in-boring-programming-jobs)
13. [Is it normal for a company not to contact you after a lengthy interview to let you know you didn't get the job?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/3598/is-it-normal-for-a-company-not-to-contact-you-after-a-lengthy-interview-to-let-y)
14. [Where can I go take a nap during the day?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/2772/where-can-i-go-take-a-nap-during-the-day)
15. [Is it discrimination when my boss treats me differently after finding out that I'm looking for a new job?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/11161/is-it-discrimination-when-my-boss-treats-me-differently-after-finding-out-that-i)

I went through each question and answer one-by-one to see:

1. If the question is on-topic for the site
2. If editing it would make it on-topic for the site without making the answers seem out of place
3. If there is any valuable information in the question/answers that make it popular

Here is the general workflow:

[image: Workflow for High-View Closed Questions]

(for those of you unaware, [here is the meta thread on a historical lock](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126587/what-is-a-historical-lock-and-what-is-it-used-for) on meta, and [here is an example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/184618/what-is-the-best-comment-in-source-code-you-have-ever-encountered))

## Results

1. [delete](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/911/getting-fired-on-the-second-day-how-do-i-cope-with-it) ([maple_shaft's answer](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/a/928/7945) has some good info, borderline historical lock)
2. [delete](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/12692/when-and-how-to-fire-a-unproductive-engineer) (this question would have been better as, 'When is it acceptable to ask an employee to attend training outside of work hours?', but as-is it seems to be a bit beyond help)
3. [delete](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/454/does-keeping-ones-desk-extremely-clean-appear-lazy)
4. [delete](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/572/is-it-unprofessional-to-play-games-during-lunch-hours)
5. [delete](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/10229/boss-does-not-answer-questions) (goodbye 660 rep!)
6. [delete](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/915/working-late-without-overtime-pay-good-idea-or-not)
7. [historical lock](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/10769/jokingly-told-my-boss-i-quit-on-april-fools-and-i-think-i-just-got-fired) (not sure I agree with the historical lock on this, but it's already done so I can't delete vote or flag it)
8. [delete](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/11411/how-does-a-non-team-player-answer-questions-about-team-playing)
9. [delete](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/772/is-it-acceptable-to-use-pirated-software-on-the-job) ([Mark Booth's answer](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/a/777/7945) has some good info, borderline historical lock)
10. [delete](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/12939/i-just-got-a-job-that-i-cant-afford-to-go-to-how-to-resolve)
11. [delete](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/4247/improving-social-interaction-at-work)
12. [delete](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/2951/stuck-in-boring-programming-jobs)
13. [delete](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/3598/is-it-normal-for-a-company-not-to-contact-you-after-a-lengthy-interview-to-let-y)
14. [delete](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/2772/where-can-i-go-take-a-nap-during-the-day) (though this has [an edit by Jeff Atwood himself](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/posts/2794/revisions) - ran out of delete votes)
15. [delete](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/11161/is-it-discrimination-when-my-boss-treats-me-differently-after-finding-out-that-i) (ran out of delete votes)

## Conclusions/Next Actions

I thought there would be a lot more high-view questions with good answers, but it really does seem that a vast majority of these were doomed by the [Stack Exchange™ MultiCollider SuperDropdown™](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11602/what-formula-should-be-used-to-determine-hot-questions) -- lots of poor answers to an off-topic question that just got featured on 'hot questions'.

For those of you with 5,000 reputation, you should have a bunch of topics in the delete queue to vote on.

There are [another 28 closed questions with over 500 views](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/search?q=closed%3Ayes+views%3A500). There are likely some very good questions out there that got closed mistakenly, or can be reopened with minor edits. Just have to figure out how to find them.

Next I am planning on tackling "[Is it appropriate/normal/appropriate if _______?](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184/what-is-the-norm-of-closing-the-question)" questions, as well as [high-votes (not just high-views) questions](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/search?q=closed%3Ayes+score%3A10).

Comment: _"goodbye 660 rep"_ - that rep will likely stay with you no matter what, see [Deleted posts should not influence reputation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/124754/deleted-posts-should-not-influence-reputation) post at MSO: _"you should keep the reputation for... * A score of 3 or greater * Visible on the site for at least 60 days"_. Score 66 > 3 and your answer is dated Mar 13, visible for more than 60 days

Answer (score 4):

I think some of these questions can be beneficial even if they are closed.

I basically went through this list, thinking, "would I ever want to link to this question in the future?" and if the answer was "yes" I did not vote to delete.

1. I'm torn, but this situation will come up from time to time. No vote from me
2. I think this is a question a lot of people will have. Also no vote
3. I actually voted to reopen this question, I've wondered about this too.
4. Ditto. This question answer is, "depends on culture" and I think the answers do a great job of this
5. I also think this is beneficial, we get questions periodically which have very similar elements to this one.
6. Torn on the overtime question. I suspect this will be useful to link as there are often questions here about OT.
7. This somehow has 10,000 views (?). I might be biased.
8. I should have closed the latest question, on "brainsizing" as a dup of this. I'm torn on this, I actually voted to reopen. Lots of people tend to have this question.
9. Meh. I would recommend lock on this, because again, this is a question a lot of people will have.
10. Complete meh, here.
11. An ok question, too poll-like. But another common workplace problem
12. Another complete meh
13. Definitely would rather lock than delete this one. We could probably link this to 1/2 the interview questions.
14. Meh?
15. Woah, 2 delete votes? This is something which also happens a lot - perhaps the title is misleading, but this also happens to a lot of people.

Comment: I voted "delete" when I thought the question was off-topic and not something I would ever refer someone else to. Are there really good answers in there you would want to refer someone asking about one of these topics to?

Comment: And of course your brilliant edit on [#4](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/572/is-it-unprofessional-to-play-games-during-lunch-hours) made me cast a reopen vote. Thanks for the sanity check!