# Shouldn't this question be edited to make it constructive?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, suggested-edits

[Can I trust employers that make the first move?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/52/can-i-trust-employers-that-make-the-first-move)

1. Fact: It's impossible to answer either 'Yes' or 'No' to this question.
2. As currently stated, anecdotes and "guesses" about a party's motivation for making an unsolicited offer are the best way to answer this question.

So I wonder:

1. Should we close this question and create a new one?
2. Or should we edit this question to say something like: "How should I respond to an unsolicited job offer? Is there anything that I should bear in mind or consider?"

Comment: I suggest reading and becoming familiar with - http://workplace.stackexchange.com/faq

Comment: @enderland: Thanks, enderland. What specifically did you mean?

Answer (score 9):

> Fact: It's impossible to answer either 'Yes' or 'No' to this question.

Good. Straight-up yes/no questions tend to be lousy and encourage lazy answers.

> As currently stated, anecdotes and "guesses" about a party's motivation for making an unsolicited offer are the best way to answer this question.

No, those are pretty lousy ways to answer the question. A good answer would involve guidance for gauging the *actual* motivation, which at least a couple of existing answers do.

> Or should we edit this question [...]

Editing is always preferable to closing, if you are able to resolve outstanding issues by doing so.

Also note that this question has already been [discussed](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35/do-we-have-a-quality-control-issue) and edited based on that discussion.